# Howto retrieve the running qt version in qt5?

Tags: qt5

I want to know the version of Qt my app is currently running with?

Not the aboutQt Dialog of QMessageBox or QApplication!

Is there a string or a int which defines the Qt version?
Or any API call?

I'm using Qt 5.4.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the global qVersion function: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qVersion

```
const char * qVersion()
```

> Returns the version number of Qt at run-time as a string (for example, "4.1.2"). This may be a different version than the version the application was compiled against.